# Should this suggested edit have been approved?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

I recently found [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5303780), creating two new tags ([sitefinity-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sitefinity-7) and [babaganoush-sitefinity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/babaganoush-sitefinity)) and adding [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23).

I was about to reject the edit (too minor, as there were other issues with the post that weren't fixed) when I saw that the edit had already been unanimously approved.

In the future, should I approve edits such as this? If so, why?

Comment: Aren't tags important enough ? To get attention from concerned people that use the "interesting" tab only ?

Comment: If the tag's are not _wrong_, I would say it's enough. Adding the language tag is a strong reason to approve the edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Folks sometimes approach me when they see my Stack Overflow T shirt, and talk about their experience on the site. There are 10+ SO users in my building alone.

Chief complaints:

- I got down voted
- I didn't get an answer, nobody viewed my question

The *most common* causes of not getting attention on your question initially is a bad non-descriptive title, and the omission of a very important tag. Folks will post questions about an API, but neglect to say they're doing stuff in Python. It's important.

If an edit makes a question stand a *better* chance of getting an answer than it would otherwise, or the user having a good experience, then it should probably be accepted. Adding a period or wrapping random things in `inline code` isn't going to help a question get an answer or folks have a better experience. Leaving a lot of stuff that should have been edited is also not going to be much help.

So, don't ask yourself "Should (criteria) be accepted?" Just think "Will this edit result in (1) higher quality, (2) the user getting a good answer or (3) the user having a better experience than they would have otherwise?"

If you make it any more complicated, then you run into this awkward decision paralysis and that tends to make reviewing not be so much fun.

Answer (score 1):

The tags improve visibility to the specific topics so they are always helpful to have, and maybe the editor wasn't sure what how to edit the other issues because they were confusing (I'm just pondering). I've seen questions which are riddled with spelling and grammar errors to the point where you aren't sure how to make the question clearer.

So, in my opinion, you should approve tag edits because then more people could see the question, (some may understand the question better and then edit it so everybody can understand).

Comment: `The tags improve visibility to the specific topics` That's only true of one of them, 2 of the tags never existed before and probably won't exist for much longer.

Comment: @MrLore I was talking about tags in general as the only edit.

Comment: @MrLore: What's wrong with the tags? They are on point as it refers to the Babaganoush SDK used with Sitefinity. http://blog.falafel.com/Blogs/-in-tags/tags/Babaganoush

Comment: @Noob And you shouldn't be.  Certain tag edits can be significant changes (sometimes good, sometimes bad), resulting in radically different visibility to a question.  Some tag changes have virtually no effect on the question at all.  Saying, "It changed tags, therefore it's a major improvement" is simply false.  In fact, the majority of tag edits I see are super minor and won't have any noticeable effect on the visibility of the question (either good or bad).  However, there are the occasional times where a question is missing a key language tag and adding it is a significant improvement.

Comment: @staticx The problem with the tags is that they add zero additional visibility to the question.  Nobody is going to find the question because of those tags that wouldn't otherwise have found it.  The question is also a pretty poor question, so if it ends up being deleted, it'll bring the tags with it as there are no other questions to keep those tags alive.

Comment: @Servy: I will give you that it is not a great question. The Babaganoush tag should be allowed in the future, is what I am saying. Don't just include the Sitefinity tag. I think the user is following the convention of creating canonical answers by answering their own question. That's allowed on SO too.

Comment: @staticx I never said that the tag isn't a valid tag, nor did anyone else.  We've merely said that it's not really improving the question to add that tag, because it's not.  It *can't*.

Comment: @Servy: Mr.Lore did in his answer above.

Comment: @staticx Then reply to *that answer* with your concerns with the points it raises.

Comment: @Servy: I did and I replied to his first comment on this answer so my comment was relevant then until you interjected :). I think you are confused

Comment: @staticx His comment on this answer states that the tags don't add any visibility.  They don't.  Whether they are tags that have a right to exist or not, they aren't adding any visibility.

Comment: @Servy: Ok, got it.

Comment: and his comment was due to my poor wording because I was speaking of tags in general, not the specific tags as adding visibility. Sorry.

Answer (score -2):

> I was about to reject the edit (**too minor, as there were other issues with the post** that weren't fixed) when I saw that the edit had already been unanimously approved.

Too right. That is how it's supposed to be done, unfortunately it's impossible to compete with the robo-reviewers. Personally, I'd remove those tags manually now you can't roll it back.

[babaganoush-sitefinity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/babaganoush-sitefinity) is utterly useless. We already have [sitefinity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sitefinity) which has all the questions shared in it, this babaganoush thing appears to be a [plugin which less than 40 people have ever used](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Babaganoush.Sitefinity/). There's no code in the question and really the whole thing feels off-topic, though I'd probably leave it to someone more familiar with it.

Comment: No, don't remove the Babaganoush tag. It is an SDK that is an enhancement to Sitefinity. It is relevant. http://blog.falafel.com/Blogs/-in-tags/tags/Babaganoush. Look what happens when you type babaganoush C# sitefinity into google now: https://www.google.com/search?q=babganoush+C%23+sitefinity&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a